# if condition met, take user to another page

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am having a bit of difficult in figuring out this one. I have couple of conditions for a phone verification. I want to take the user to a different page if the conditions are met... how can I best do this with JavaScript?

Please see code attached.

```js
function validatePhone(){

  var phone  = document.getElementById("phone1").value;
  if(phone.length === 0) {
    console.log("phone number is required.");
    producePrompt("Phone number is required.", "messagePrompt", "red");
    return false;
   } 

  if(!phone.match(/^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-.]?([0-9]{3})[-.]?([0-9]{4})$/)) 
  {
   producePrompt("Please enter a valid Phone number.", "messagePrompt", "red");
   return false;
   }
   producePrompt("valid Number", "messagePrompt", "green");
   return true;
  }

  function producePrompt(message, promptLocation, color) {
   document.getElementById(promptLocation).innerHTML = message;
   document.getElementById(promptLocation).style.color = color;
  }

  function remove_msg(){
   producePrompt(" ", "messagePrompt", "red");
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <p>Please enter your phone number below:</p>
  <input type="tel" name="phone1" id="phone1" placeholder="(000)000-0000" onchange="validatePhone()"/ onmouseover="remove_msg()">
  <label for="" id="messagePrompt"></label>
  <br>
    <input id="button" type="button"  value="send message" onclick="validatePhone()"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: Give your form an action.  Use Javascript to change the action before you submit.

Comment: your form element needs action attribute

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll work on it.